# Insert character into SQL string

Tags: sql, insert-update

I have an nvarchar column I need to insert a hyphen at fixed points within the string. The hyphen need to go between the rightmost character and the next, and again in the 3rd position from the right, such as:
column value is

```
0000050704
```

and I need it to be

```
0000050-70-4
```

or value is

```
0555256321
```

and it should be

```
0555256-32-1
```

Can't see how this is done. Can anyone give me a little help?

Comment: If it's SQL Server, `STUFF()` is made just for this...

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the strings can be a variable length, you'll need to use REVERSE() or lots of nasty looking LEN() values in your expression.

```
declare @txt varchar(100) = '0000050704'

--If using SQL Server, the STUFF() function is your friend
select REVERSE(STUFF(STUFF(REVERSE(@txt), 2, 0, '-'), 5, 0, '-'))

--if not you'll need to concatenate SUBSTRING()s
select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@txt), 1, 1) + '-' + SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@txt),2, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@txt),4, LEN(@txt)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You  can use this easy function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SetHyphen] (@S varchar(50)) RETURNS varchar(52)
BEGIN
RETURN STUFF(STUFF(@S,LEN(@S)-2,0,'-'),LEN(@S)+1,0,'-')
END
```

For example:

```
select [dbo].[SetHyphen]('0000050704')
0000050-70-4
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your SQL server. Please check the documentation on how to manipulate strings - I will  suppose SUBSTRING function.

In MS SQL Server you can do sth. like this:

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET 
    YourFieldName = 
        SUBSTRING(YourFieldName, 1,7) + "-" + 
        SUBSTRING(YourFieldName, 7,2) + "-" +
        SUBSTRING(YourFieldName, 9,1)
```

This will split your field content in three parts and rebuild it with separators...

Before running the query I will suggest you try it as plain SELECT to see if it works as needed:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(YourFieldName, 1,7) + "-" + 
    SUBSTRING(YourFieldName, 7,2) + "-" +
    SUBSTRING(YourFieldName, 9,1)
FROM YourTableName
```

Take care that the query is without WHERE condition and thus will affect ALL rows of your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @inputString VARCHAR(100) = 'abcde'
DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @outputString = COALESCE(@outputString + '-', '') + SUBSTRING(@inputString, number, 1)
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P' AND number <= LEN(@inputString)

SELECT @outputString AS 'Output String'
```