# How to add decimal to numbers stored as text?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some currency values stored in a table in a  varchar(50) column. Unfortunately I cannot alter the data being imported, and the values are stored without decimal points. I need to get the values from the varchar column in a format where I can divide them by 100 to add the decimal. It would be awesome if I could just update the column to add the decimal.

I've tried CONVERTing and CASTing, yet when I divide by 100 it appears to simply truncate the two rightmost digits instead of actually performing the division.

Ultimately I just need the decimal points added to this column and am totally baffled.

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300683/insert-character-into-sql-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
  declare @Currency as varchar(50)
  set @Currency = 8000;

  declare @CurrencyDecimal as decimal(18,2) 
  set @CurrencyDecimal = @Currency /100

  select cast(@CurrencyDecimal as varchar(50))
```

and/or this:

```
  select cast(@Currency / 100 as decimal(18,2) )

  select convert(DECIMAL(18,2),@Currency / 100)
```

if you need to update:

```
 update t1
 set Currency = cast(Currency as decimal(18,2) )
 where = -- some condition
```

[Data Types (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

[CAST and CONVERT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much! This did the trick beautifully! I will admit not not understanding why it works, though. Can you tell me what concept I should study to understand this better?  (I am still relatively new to this site, so even though I upvoted your answer, they're not counting my votes yet.) :)

Comment: you need to know about data types and how can they be converted.. i have edit my answer with two links

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the STUFF function to respond to this request :
"It would be awesome if I could just update the column to add the decimal."

```
UPDATE [table] SET [column] = STUFF([column],LEN([column])-1,0,'.')
```