# Insert Percentage Symbol in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage, symbols

I need to insert `%` Symbol on Var. on Month
I tried

- + '%'
- Char37
- & '%'

All gave me error messages.

```
CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(MonthCost.LastCost, 0) <> 0 THEN (NowCost.LastCost - MonthCost.LastCost) / MonthCost.LastCost ELSE 0 END * 100 AS Numeric(10, 2)) AS [Var. On Month]
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: How did you try those different options? If you get an error message, share the message text.

Comment: May be this will be helpful.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300683/insert-character-into-sql-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must **first** cast your numeric value into a string type and than you can use the `+` for concatenation:

```
SELECT CAST((100.0/25) AS VARCHAR(100)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the SQL query should look like this to get it working

```
CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(MonthCost.LastCost, 0) <> 0 THEN (NowCost.LastCost - MonthCost.LastCost) / MonthCost.LastCost ELSE 0 END * 100 AS Numeric(10, 2)) AS Varcahr(50)) + '%' AS [Var. On Month]
```

Comment: Hi Steve, Great, that you found a solution! This is exactly the same as you find in my answer (just replace the `(100.0/25)` with your own calculation expression). The point is, that you want to use the `+` sign on strings, which means *concatenation*. Without the previous `CAST` the `+` sees a number and tries to `add` the expression `%` which must break. As my answer solves your question actually, it would be nice to accept and vote on it. Thx